# Neo4j subdivide a path by his node relationship

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I would like to subdivide the path of the nodes at the places where a relation to a type starts or ends.

[image]

At the example I got nodes 1-5 and I would like to have parts/segments like this:

- part 1 (1, 1.1 )
- part 2 (1.1, 1,2 )
- part 3 ( 1.2, 1.3 )
- part 4 ( 1.3, 2, 3 )
- part 5 ( 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4, 4.1 )
- part 6 ( 4.1,5 )

I something like this possible?

Comment: What is your expected result? A row of Part1 to Part6? or columns of Part1 to Part6?

Comment: Would be nice, if I get a row for each part with their points